# Is there a way to override Python's built-in function int() and float()?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want to override Python's built-in `int()` function such that:

1. When the argument to `int()`, say `x`, is an instance of my own type, which is a subclass of `int`, return the same instance with no changes.
2. When the argument to `int()` is any other types, just call the built-in `int()`.
   It look something like this:

```
def new_int(x, *args, **kwargs):
    if isinstance(x, MyInt):
        return x
    else:
        return builtins.int(x, *args, **kwargs)
```

I want to somehow shadow the built-in `int()` function so I can use `new_int()` in other parts of my code without explicitly changing all occurrences of `int()` to `new_int()`.

I tried overriding `__int__` (in `MyInt` class), but it seems like CPython will not let me output a subclass of type `int()` (i.e., `MyInt` in the code above). This is why I am considering overriding `int()` altogether. The same issue is also with `str()` (say I do `MyStr`, a subclass of `UserString`) and `float()` (e.g., `MyFloat`, a subclass of `float`).

I also tried this in my package's `__init__.py`:

```
import sys
module = sys.modules['builtins']
module.int = lambda obj: obj.__int__() # if type(obj) is MyInt, then it will call its own __int__, which returns itself
sys.modules['builtins'] = module
```

I was hoping this will do, but it breaks other existing modules, e.g.,:

```
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 991, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 975, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 671, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 779, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 883, in get_code
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 518, in _classify_pyc
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 54, in _unpack_uint32
AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'from_bytes'
```

Comment: I wonder if you could tell us more about why you want to do this? There may be a better solution available, but it's hard to tell.

Comment: @larsks Use int as an example: I need an `int` subclass that behaves just like `int` with additional features. I don't want users to remove that feature by coercing the value back to the built-in `int` type, but preserve the feature if the input to `int()` is my subclass object. I have similar subclasses of float and str.

Comment: This sounds like an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). What is the problem you are trying to solve with it?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there's a clean way for you as a library provider to override this, nor should you, IMO. I'd recommend inheriting from the base class and overriding `__int__` to raise some exception to say, "Can't use this"

```py
class NotSupportedError(Exception):
    """Raise when a method is not supported"""

class MyInt(int):
    def __int__(self):
         raise NotSupportedError("This is not supported for MyInt")
```

Or, if you look at [the docs for NotImplemented](https://docs.python.org/3/library/exceptions.html#NotImplementedError), they recommend setting to `None`, but that ends up throwing a TypeError anyway, so I'd probably just throw some exception of your own.

This feels like the least amount of surprise from a consumers point of view.

Comment: Thanks! That's in fact exactly what I am doing at the moment, basically not allowing this `int` to `MyInt` coercion. I was hoping someone can find a way that makes `int()` do nothing. Perhaps you are right, maybe there is no good ways to do this cleanly! Thanks again.